Process under systemd (journald) doesn't log stdout?
I have a process that I've written that logs several lines to stdout on startup:
Remote Input Daemon starting...
Creating evdev device... done.
Filling keys list array... done.
Setting up listening socket... done.
Listening on 0.0.0.0:8063...

...and they are displayed using fprintf:
fprintf(stdout, "Remote Input Daemon starting...\r\n");

However, systemd doesn't display them nor does journalctl.  What am I doing wrong?
Here is my unit file:
[Unit]
Description=Remote Input Service Daemon

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/sofakng/Applications/Distrobox/risd/risd
StandardOutput=journal                     

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target


fprintf might be buffering. Have you made sure the things you print have actually been flushed out to stdout before you looked in the journal?

I’ve waited hours and nothing from stdout is ever logged. If I run it from the console (w/o) systemd it logs to the console just fine.

ah, are you reading the right journal? (i.e., are you running journalctl -u if this is a user unit, or without -u if this is a system unit?)
